# Trying to add portraits to dialogue balloon using the Dialogue plugin, followed official tutorital to a T and it doesn't work

Tags: godot, godot4

I'm trying to add character sprites / portraits to the dialogue ballons I made/modified using the Dialogue Plugin.

I was following the [offical tutorital](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X0e-n7dbff8) to the letter with the necessary changes to link to the files I want to use. But it won't work and I've checked the code and compared and constrasted multiple times and can't see what I've done wrong.

I even repeated the process from scratch and still cant get it to work. No problem loading the custom balloon, it just won't include the images.

Here is the code I added / changed

```
@onready var portrait: TextureRect = %Portrait
```

---

```
var portrait_path: String = "res://Draft Files/Milo Draft.png" % dialogue_line.character.to_lower()
    if FileAccess.file_exists(portrait_path):
        portrait.texture = load (portrait_path)
    else:
        portrait.texture = null
```

Comment: Did you check the portrait_path variable? Is the % dialogue_line.character.to_lower() part actually doing something? Don't see a placeholder to replace it. Also which system are you on? If you're using linux putting whitespaces into folder names will break it

Comment: I just copied what the tutorial was saying - new to coding so I'm not sure what most things do.  I assumed I must do something to get it to work but there is no visible thing I need to replace like an asset name etc

Comment: Try to debug your code with breakpoints or print statements to see what is going wrong. Also remove the whitespaces in the image file names. This could also make it break.

Comment: Comes up with - - - E 0:00:00:0746   balloon.gd:40 @ @dialogue_line_setter(): not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: this will not help you and is expected. Since you added an argument, which is not used in the string. It's more interesting if the if clause returns true.

Comment: any advice then on what to do then? Again I followed the tutorial exactly using the same base - all that has changed is the file name since I'm attempting to add my own file

Comment: Again read my suggestions. try a filename without whitespaces. and add following into your code directly under "if file_exists(..)": print(portrait_path). Then start your game and see if the file path is logged and correct

Comment: did both things but still came up with the same error on the same line - var portrait_path: String = "res://Draft Files/Milo_Draft.png" % dialogue_line.character.to_lower()

Comment: ohhh it's an error. Sorry did not read that. remove everything after ".png" in that line, cause you dont use it. This should resolve the error in the line

Comment: Absolute legend thank you! Been trying to resolve that for two days.

Comment: You're welcome .} Did this resolve your problem completly? If so, I will write it as an answer to this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the usage of the % operator without a placeholder. This leads to an error which stops code execution.

Changing that part fixed the error:

```
var portrait_path: String = "res://Draft Files/Milo_Draft.png"
```

Also recommended to remove the whitespace in the file and directory names, because this could lead to problems on some systems.